# Как отобразить контейнер при наведении курсора на элемент?

Tags: jquery, css

Хочу сделать что-то типа `hover`'a  при наведении курсора на кнопку. В качестве ховера должен всплывать контейнер, в котором будет информация и несоклько кнопок. В сети нашел информацию о том,что hover дива можно сделать с помощью [css.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210033/using-only-css-show-div-on-hover-over-a) и с помошью  [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30084561/jquery-hover-keep-popup-open). Собственно вопрос заключается в том как удерживать всплывший контейнер открытым\оставлять его открытым,если пользователь держит на нем курсор?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант на CSS с использованием `transition-delay`:

```css
.popup {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition-delay: 1s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 1s;
  transition-property: visibility;
    -webkit-transition-property: visibility;
    -moz-transition-property: visibility;
}

button:hover ~ .popup {
  visibility: visible;
  transition-delay: unset;
  -webkit-transition-delay: unset;
  -moz-transition-delay: unset;
}

.popup:hover {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
<div class="popup">Popup content</div>
```

Вариант с использованием jQuery:

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').each(function() {
    var timer = null
      , popup = $('~ .popup', this);
    $(this).add(popup).mouseenter(function() {
      clearInterval(timer);
      popup.show();
    }).mouseleave(function() {
      timer = setTimeout(function() {
        popup.hide();
      }, 1000);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.popup {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button>Button 1</button>
  <div class="popup">Popup content 1</div>
</div>
<div>
  <button>Button 2</button>
  <div class="popup">Popup content 2</div>
</div>
<div>
  <button>Button 3</button>
  <div class="popup">Popup content 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: что значит в данном случае оператор ~  перед селектором   ?

Comment: @Iga, это тоже CSS селектор (https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators).

Comment: так и не понял для чего эта штука применяется(поггуглю еще. у меня такой вариант не сработал. переделал немножко ваш вариант с использованием jquery(решил написать,вдруг у кого-то возникнет такая же проблема): $(function() {
        var timer = null
          , popup = $('.user-menu');
        $('#button_menu').add(popup).mouseenter(function() {
          clearInterval(timer);
            popup.show();
        }).mouseleave(function() {
          timer = setTimeout(function() {
            popup.hide();
          }, 1000);
        });
    });
так все работает. большое спасибо